# How to get Google Spreadsheet cell link with gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-account, gspread

There is a single Google spreadsheet document.
After selecting the very first `A1` cell from a right-click pull-down menu I choose: `Get Link to this Cell` command.

The URL link is now stored in a memory and it can be pasted into any text editor. The copied cell's URL link would look like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/f8s9HO0sidw9qIGwuqYq1wFFb9QWWpuFIXE3flYcgBG1/edit?ts=7559594f#gid=2879414198&range=A1

Question: How to get the the same cell's link using `gspread` in Python?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First you'll need to generate OAuth2 credentials:
http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html

You'll need to create a new authorization object in your Python using the OAuth2 credentials:

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

Then you need to create a connection to the worksheet:

```
# If you want to be specific, use a key (which can be extracted from
# the spreadsheet's url)
yoursheet = gc.open_by_key('0BmgG6nO_6dprdS1MN3d3MkdPa142WFRrdnRRUWl1UFE')

# Or, if you feel really lazy to extract that key, paste the entire url
yoursheet = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Bm...FE&hl')
```

Then you can grab the cell you want

```
val = yoursheet.acell('B1').value
```

All code was pulled from the gspread Github basic usage with minor tweaks https://github.com/burnash/gspread

Cheers!

Comment: `val = yoursheet.acell('B1').value` command returns the value the cell is filled (populated) with. But my question was how to get the Cell's URL - the  URL link you get when you right-click and run `Get Link To This Cell` command.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think Google exposes that functionality via the Sheets API. I suppose there are a few arduous ways of replicating opening the page and extracting the value that way, but I don't know if there's any easy way to do this.